# How to parse the json data which is received by a url that is json_enocoded in php

Tags: php, json, parsing, xml-parsing

I wanted to parse the json data i got, i have already did this these types, but some how this was different , i just wanted to know how i can take a single array or single array value from the output.  Below is the code I used to get the content from the url to convert to the json data:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));
$data = json_encode($xml);
print_r($data);
```

I Tried :

```
echo $data['OperationRequest']['RequestId'];

print_r($data->OperationRequest['RequestId']);
```

etc
After i printed the data i got this

[Click here to see how i got the output](http://pastebin.com/AfvUxJE2)

Comment: You seem to be encoding XML to JSON, and then trying to use the json like an array/object.
You need to decode the JSON back to an array/object before you can access it, so try....
$data = json_decode(json_encode($xml));
print_r($data);

Comment: when i did that i got an output like this http://pastebin.com/PdLz8z5e , Now how can i take the value ?

Comment: json_decode() converts a json string to objects, which can be accessed using $data->OperationRequest->RequestId If you would prefer an array, try $data = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true); You can read the documentation here http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: Thank , it worked !

Answer (score 1):

So it worked , So now i could get the data form the json like this

```
$fdata = $data->Items->ASIN;
$img =$fdata->LargeImage->URL;
```